# SSDT Generate Script Producing Syntax Error on SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-data-project

I'm using the "Generate Script" feature in SSDT to create a database script.  However, the script that is generated has a syntax error, according to SSMS when I execute the script.  The code with the error is:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
       FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
       WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
        SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON(INCREMENTAL = OFF),
            MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT = OFF,
            DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
        WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
END
```

The error is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 208 Incorrect syntax near
>   'INCREMENTAL'. Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 211 Incorrect syntax
>   near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table
>   expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context
>   clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 211 Incorrect syntax near
>   'IMMEDIATE'.

As far as I can tell, the syntax being generated was deprecated in SQL Server 2012 CTP1.

I'm using Visual Studio version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 with SSDT version 14.0.609.18.  I'm executing this script against SQL Server 11.0.6020.

Note that I'm able to publish from Visual Studio, Schema Compare from Visual Studio, apply this schema via a DACPAC upgrade in SSMS or VS, and I'm also able to apply the build's DACPAC via DacFx without error.  I only get this error when executing the raw script.

If I remove the offending code it works as expected.  I do **need** to have the script for one particular case.  I'm just trying to figure out why SSDT is creating bad syntax.  I would prefer to not have to have a checklist of manual edits I need to do to the generated script before deployment.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you have sqlcmd mode enabled in SSMS? (Query -> SQLCMD Mode)?

Comment: Yes, the syntax error occurs with SQLCMD mode enabled.  I'm also targeting a SQL Server 2012 database in my project properties.

Comment: Well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380348/how-to-generate-sql-server-2012-scripts-in-sql-server-2008-r2 suggests to comment out those two blocks.

Comment: (works fine for me too)